# Forcinge the codepage of a file so that it can show characters encoded with windows-1256 correctly?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, arabic, codepages

> I need to save a plain text file with Arabic characters in it, and
>   Arabic characters must be appear as Arabic when the file will be opened.

I can insert the names without problem using `Encoding.GetEncoding(1256)` and save the file - again using 1256 as the `StreamWriter`'s codepage.

However, when viewing the resulting file in Notepad++ the characters do not appear correctly and I have to deliberately switch the codepage back to 1256 for them to appear in Arabic.

I am then transmitting the file to a third party, but they cannot change the codepage (I have no idea why!) and therefore cannot read the Arabic.

Is there any way I can save the file so that the codepage to be used is "embedded" in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the file as UTF-8. That should automatically include a magic BOM (Byte Order Mark) in the beginning of the file so applications opening the file will know it is encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Works :)  Just for my understanding, why does encoding with 1256 NOT put the BOM as 1256?  Or, same question in a different way, why do I have to say UTF-8 and not 1256?

Comment: Encoding with 1256 will only can encode Arabic and some Latin characters. and UTF-8 can encode all supported character sets at once. So if your file contains different language with Arabic then its really gonna messed up if you have planned to use 1256. @BlueChippy

Comment: There is no BOM for 1256. General BOMs that e.g. Notepad can recognize when opening a file are only UTF-8 and UTF-16, all other files are saved without any information about the coding used.